# Logout doesn't work with DIGEST authentication

Tags: orbeon

I have installed `Orbeon Forms 2018.2.201901010020 CE` in `Tomcat-8.5.37` and tried to use the new logout button of the user menu - the login worked already in previous orbeon releases.
Specifying  **FORM** as authentication method in the login section of the web.xml, all works smoothly.
But using FORM authentication one has to save the passwords in clear text, this is something to avoid.
So I tried **DIGEST** as authentication method, which permits to save encrypted passwords.
The login works and the user menu reports the logged-in user.
But the logout doesn't invalidate the session. Instead of showing the orbeon logout page, the form runner home page is shown and in the user menu the user is still displayed as logged in.
And clicking once more the logout button, all remains the same: the  form runner home page is displayed with the user already logged in.

In the `properties-local.xml` I inserted the property for the user menu and for the container authentication:

```
  <property
    as="xs:boolean"
    name="oxf.fr.authentication.user-menu.enable"
    value="true"/>
  <property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.authentication.method"
    value="container"
  />
```

The users and roles are defined in `tomcat_users.xml`.

In the `web.xml` I changed  the url-pattern in the security constraint for the form runner from `<url-pattern>/fr/auth</url-pattern>`  to
`<url-pattern>/fr/*</url-pattern>`, so tomcat asked the authentication for all `fr` pages:

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Form Runner</web-resource-name>
            <!-- <url-pattern>/fr/auth</url-pattern> original -->
                 <url-pattern>/fr/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>orbeon-user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

For the DIGEST authentication I used **DIGEST** in the `login-config` of the `web.xml` and added the **`CredentialHandler`** in the realm in the `server.xml`.

```
        <login-config>
            <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
            <!-- <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>   -->
            <form-login-config>
                <form-login-page>/fr/login</form-login-page>
                <form-error-page>/fr/login-error</form-error-page>
            </form-login-config>
        </login-config>
```

```
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase">
           <!-- <CredentialHandler
     className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
              algorithm="md5" saltLength="0" iterations="1" /> -->
    </Realm>
```

In the tests I first opened the page `http://localhost/8080/orbeon/home/` . This isn't an **fr** page, so it will be displayed without asking for a password.
Then I chosed the **bookshelf** application. This is an fr page, so a page for the authentication pops up.
With the FORM authentication the orbeon login page is displayed:
[image: orbeon login]
With the DIGEST authentication a tomcat login page is displayed:
[image: tomcat login]

In both cases, after a successful login the bookshelf summary page is displayed and the user menu shows the logged in user.
[image: bookshelf summary page with user menu]

In the DIGEST authentication after clicking the logout button  the next page displayed is the form runner home page instead of the orbeon logout page. The user remains logged in and the username is displayed in the user menu.
Clicking once more the logout button, all remains the same: the  form runner home page is displayed with the user already logged in:
[image: form runner home page after logout]

Nearby the links to the two orbeon logs:
orbeon.log  for the **FORM** authentication  [orbeon log form authentication](https://gist.github.com/hoila/2ee0a7d2be25b421155cc4e0243a1348)
orbeon.log for the **DIGEST** authentication  [orbeon log DIGEST authentication](https://gist.github.com/hoila/3ce468a69dc9e7cafc24f92d09e7f39c)

NB. In the orbeon DIGEST log I saw broken pipe errors, in the orbeon FORM log i didn't see this errors.

What I have to change so that the logout works also with the DIGEST authentication?

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: I don't think your premise is correct: using form-based authentication does not require you to store passwords in plain text. Form-based auth will transmit the username/password as Base64-encoded over the wire, that is true, but you must use HTTPS/TLS anyway over the wire. Where did you get the idea that using `FORM` would require you to store passwords as plain text?

Comment: I supposed that specifying 
`<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.method" value="container" />` 
tomcat would make the authentication.
And reading the documentation for the digested passwords 
I read: _For each of the standard Realm implementations, the user's password (by default) is stored in clear text._

In my tests, to use a Credential handler I had to specify DIGEST as authentication method in the `login-config`  of `web.xml`.

All the examples I saw used **DIGEST** as authentication method in the `web.xml`.

Comment: 1. It is correct that if you specify `container` then Tomcat is supposed to take care of things. 2. In your sentence, the key is "by default". Don't use the default and have the passwords digested in your *database*. 3. You are confusing the `DIGEST` authentication method, which I believe almost nobody uses, and the general idea of *digesting* passwords in the database. You want the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 1):

In short, what I would recommend:

1. Don't use `DIGEST` in `web.xml`. Use `FORM`. Most web apps use some kind of form-based authentication.
2. Make sure to use HTTPS, not plain HTTP.
3. Make sure to use a security realm which does not store passwords in clear in the database. This is independent from whether you are using form-based authentication or not.
4. With `BASIC` auth, it is not be possible to log out easily. The same might be the case with `DIGEST`. I am not sure that's a problem worth solving.

See also [HTTP Basic auth password storage more secure than Digest auth](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18626/http-basic-auth-password-storage-more-secure-than-digest-auth). My understanding is that `DIGEST` is out of date and less secure than properly done form-based auth over HTTPS with *proper* digesting of passwords in your database.

Comment: _3) Make sure to use a security realm which ...._    
I installed **openldap** and used then the JNDIRealm with form-based authentication and the logout works fine :)  
  
_2) Make sure to use HTTPS, not plain HTTP_  
My goal was to permit to reproduce the problem with minimal effort. I've specified the four changes made to the downloaded software.  
Did you have difficulties to reproduce the problem?  
  
_4) .... I am not sure that's a problem worth solving._   
Advice for my ex coworkers - (DataSourceRealm)  
- not enable the user menu   
- to inform the users to close the browser